# Why doesn't jQuery Mobile work with 1.9.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm sorry. I can't find an answer with Google alone. How do I include jQuery 1.9.1 and jquery Mobile in my project?

**Edit**

I know how to include javascript files. I mean to say, jquery mobile is incompatibile with jQuery 1.9.1.

See [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3wzTr/) to demonstrate.

Including either jQuery Mobile framework with 1.9.1 in the jsFiddle above causes the tap to not to work. jQuery 1.8.3 and below works.

Code from the fiddle:

```
<div id='box'>TAP ME</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#box').bind('tap',function(event) {
        alert('Thanks!');
    });    
});
```

Comment: Seriously? What have you been trying to Google? http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: You can include it like any other javascript file.

Comment: Do you mean images dont appear when you host the files locally?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I was unclear. I meant 1.9.1 is incompatible with jquery mobile. See updated question.

Comment: use JQM 1.3.0 along with it, jQuery Mobile 1.3.0 is not checked on JSfiddle and remove `.ready(function` see this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/3wzTr/1/

Comment: Thanks @Omar, but I need `tap`

Comment: replace `click` with `tap` and check it on your mobile. `vclick` stimulates `tap` but on desktops. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/3wzTr/2/

Comment: `tap` doesn't work on JSfiddle, but it works on a normal local HTML page, desktop and mobile.

Comment: If you select jQuery 1.8.3 in jsfiddle, `tap` works on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You really should have checked official site before posting this question.

Every jQuery Mobile version is locked to the certain jQuery version range.

For example:

- [jQuery Mobile 1.1](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/04/13/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0/) supports jQuery 1.6.4 or 1.7.1
- [jQuery Mobile 1.2](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/) supports jQuery 1.7.0 to 1.8.2 while I can confirm it works also with jQuery 1.8.3. and WILL NOT WORK with anything greater then 1.8.3
- [jQuery Mobile 1.3](http://api.jquerymobile.com/) supports jQuery 1.7.0 to 1.9.1 while I can confirm it works also with jQuery 2